# When using the builder pattern, is there a way to pass data from one of the objects being used to build to another object?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, builder

I have two objects that are put together to create another object in a builder pattern in Java.  One is a PayloadData abstract class object, the other is a HeaderData object (not abstract).  They inherit from an interface called MessageElement.  However, I need the PayloadData object to pass its size (I already have code that creates a variable in Payload that has this stored) to the Header object.  How can I do this?  PayloadData is an abstract object that is overriden by "Type"Payload (the type of data stored by payload).

HeaderData has a method for calculating overall message size:

```
    public int messageSize() //This method is finsihed already, but needs to be fixed.
    {

        return PayloadData.elementSize() + 16; //Something here need to be fixed.
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

PayloadData has this method (which is overridden by the class that inherits from it:

```
public int elementSize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

The concrete object has this: to override it:

```
    @Override
public  int elementSize() //This is the one override that I think will be needed.  Need to figure out how to pass this to
//HeaderData, as right now it is not accepting it.
{
    return (48 + 184 * tracksInMessage());

}
```

I think I need to modify the builder pattern I'm using to let HeaderData access elementSize, but how should I do that?

Remember there is a class that is ultimately built, a Message class in this case, which is assembled from the HeaderData class and the class that inherits from PayloadData, and there is a builder class and a class that uses the builder class to create Message objects.

Here is the pattern I followed by the way, I replaced Burger with PayloadData and replaced ColdDrink with HeaderData but made it a concrete object:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm

Comment: So Message is the class your trying to build, and two of the elements that are needed are PayloadData and HeadderData right?  Also, PayloadData needs a value stored in HeadderData?  Does it need this value in order to instantiate, or can it be populated during Message.build()?

Comment: Just for proper organization, it would be better for PayloadData to immediately pass its size information to HeaderData ASAP, because the header is to contain an array that stores the size of the overall message.  The size information could be appended in the built class (Message), but the header is supposed to know the size anyway.

Comment: In the build() method, compute the message size based on the payload, create a copy of the header with this computed size, and store the payload and the header copy in the message. Note that what this tutorial explains is **not** the builder pattern. Here's what the builder pattern actually is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java_Example

Comment: So basically, the tutorialpoint example is wrong?  That is disturbing considering how much I've been using content on there.

Comment: It's wrong in naming "builder pattern" the code that is shown. That doesn't mean it's bad code. It's just not what the builder pattern is.

Comment: I get that.  From what I can tell, HeaderData gets a lot of data from external sources (what message number it is, what type of message, and then of course size.  Should I restructure it so that HeaderData is directly created by the Builder or the Message Class?

Comment: Well, it seems that the HeaderData is actually a big part of what you're creating. So yes, the builder should contain those various parts, and the build() method (or the Message constructor called by the build() method) should probably create the HeaderData.

Comment: Ok, I meant to put it in the same category as PayloadData, because they both contain the same data types (floats, doubles, ints, short), etc and they get put together to make the final message, but from what you are saying, the HeaderData I guess will need to be constructed in the actual message creation instead.  Thanks for the information.  Funny thing is this actually simplifies things but makes it so I have to do more work simultaneously because I need to move the HeaderData code elsewhere.

Comment: Just realized something funny.  The Payload object actually knows the size of the Message before it even gets passed onto the Message class.  This is because the Header is always 16 bytes in size, while the Payload can range in size depending on type of message, number of tracks, etc. etc.  Is there a way I can make the build process act like an two step assembly line, starting with the payloaddata which then passes itself to the next class where the Header is added to complete the message after looking at the payload data to determine the header contents?